# Shift an array without wrapping in O(1) time

Tags: arrays, optimization

I need to shift an array to the right without wrapping, for example:

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

after being right shifted by 2 becomes

[0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

This is simple to do with iteration, but would it be conceivable to do this operation in constant time?

If not, what would be the most efficient way to do this with a large array?

Comment: How do you expect to shift N values in less than N time?

Comment: I'm not sure, I thought there might be a quicker way than iterating or maybe some pointer magic. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Easy (?) enough to do if you write an indexing routine to trap an expression such as `arr[2]` and either map it to where the 2nd element is, or to return the value `0` if you've shifted things.  If you're only concerned with end-off rightward shifts you never actually have to move any data around in memory.